# IoT Edge Version 1.2 Pub Sub mqtt_broker unable to connect mosquito client from a different host

Tags: authentication, mqtt, mosquitto, azure-iot-edge, connection-refused

I was following the tutorial from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11 to setup pub sub using the built-in mqtt broker on a transparent gateway. I was able to complete the tutorial and publish and subscribe to topics with and without TLS on the same host.  However, when I try to connect from a different host I get an error in the edgeHub logs

*mqtt_broker::broker] - sending connack with: Refused(BadUserNameOrPassword)*

The same command will work on the local host but not a remote host.

Does the iotedge 1.2 edgeHub allow making client request from a different host?

Comment: I would think this part of the error is the important bit `Refused(BadUserNameOrPassword)` This implies that connections from remote hosts require the correct credentials.

Comment: The same credentials will work from the local host but they fail from a remote host.